# Authorize.net Token Expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, authorize.net, spree

So everytime a customer enters the credit card information on my site, their credit card information gets stored (partially) in the database along with the corresponding gateway payment token for Authorize.net. How long is this token good for before it expires in the production site? I'm assuming that these tokens in development or staging accounts will never expire? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the "customer_profile_id" that gets returned from Authorize.net?  If so, this token does not expire.  Be aware, that the credit card associated with the profile can expire/get cancelled/etc though, which would result in errors when you attempt to do a future purchase with that token.

Comment: That and the gateway_payment_profile_id. Do you know what's the difference and which one is more important?

Comment: Actually, both are required to submit a purchase transaction - one is at the customer level (customer_profile_id ) and one is at the payment level (customer_payment_profile_id).  You can have multiple payment profiles per customer if you wish - think multiple credit cards on file.

Comment: Check out the [CIM XML guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_XML_guide.pdf) from Authorize.net.  The activemerchant gem basically just makes this API conform to more ruby-like conventions, by turning the camel case into words separated by underscores.